# Dell XPS13 2015 Developer ed. Ubuntu 14.04 Slow wireless

Tags: 14.04, networking, dell, ethernet

my new XPS13 2015 Developper Edition came with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. It works great, except that the wireless connection is super slow (both home and at work), so slow that most page or process time out.

Here is some extra info:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
d@XPS-13:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:16062 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16062 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1664794 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1664794 (1.6 MB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:8e:8f:fb:af:cb  
      inet addr:192.168.2.4  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c68e:8fff:fefb:afcb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:70332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:83987
      TX packets:65953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:59671259 (59.6 MB)  TX bytes:26678896 (26.6 MB)
      Interrupt:19
```

Please help, this is my main production/work machine!

Thanks,

Don

Comment: What browser are you using and do you use a proxy or VPN? Even a work VPN?

Comment: I am on firefox, no VPN or proxy ( I guess)... Thanks for the quick help!
kernel version 3.13.0-65-generic

Comment: Have you ever tried using another OS?

Comment: Came with Ubuntu 14.04 and is the only OS... I am sure is a OS problem with the wifi card...

Comment: You might want to look online to see if there's a proprietary driver they neglected to install, or just call the manufacturer if it came preinstalled

Comment: I guess you could try reinstalling the drivers. Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers#answer-38700) and see if you can apply it to what you have.

Comment: Please try to use a Ubuntu 15.04 live USB/CD to see if you got faster wifi.